Movie about a disabled girl with a nasty nurse
I only remember some details but I hope someone can help. This movie was about a paralyzed girl. She can't walk and speak. She uses a stick to write on a keyboard. The girl has a very bad and nasty nurse who takes care of her. This nurse has got a boyfriend who recently left prison. After some time he takes care of the disabled girl. I think this girl was really a disabled person (not an actress). 
I watched it in the late 90s on Polish tv. I think it was some European country, maybe Belgium, Denmark or Sweden. Maybe someone knows the title of this movie?

When did you watched it? Approximate release yer? Country? Language? any other scene/character you remember?

This sounds a lot like Rolf de Heer's Dance Me to My Song from 1998.

A woman trapped in a twisted body from her bouts with the debilitating cerebral palsy communicates with the world via her computer with a voice box. Her caretaker is a short-tempered woman who begrudges the woman the care she needs. Things change when Rose bumps into a young man who starts giving her attention. This leads her to start fantasizing about a real sexual relationship. However, the caretaker takes an interest in the man, as well, which leads to the dramatic conclusion. 

The heroine was played by Heather Rose, who also co-wrote the script. She was disabled in real life and sadly died a few years later. You can find a (dubbed) clip here [WARNING: Contains nudity]. Here's a frame from the film with Heather and the keyboard she communicated with:

